# Pandas DataFrame from pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am tying to understand the following Dataframe created from pandas Series. Why does pandas returning two different Dataframes. How does adding '[]' make any difference here?

```
series = pd.Series([11,22,33])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(series)
df2 = pd.DataFrame([series])    # series inside []
```

here are the outputs:

df1:

```
    0
0   11
1   22
2   33
```

df2:

```
    0   1   2
0   11  22  33
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. So it is like passing list of list [ [11,22,22 ] ] ??

Comment: yes in case of `pd.Dataframe([series]])`, you are passing list of list, I have explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of [series], you are passing a `list` of `lists` and pandas considers each list inside `[]` as a row

For instance, if you have following,

```
 pd.DataFrame([series,series])
```

which is similar as doing

```
pd.DataFrame([[11,22,33],[11,22,33]])
```

You will have two rows, with `3 columns` each (in your case, you have `1 row` and `3 columns` as you have one list inside a `[] (list)` )

```
    0   1   2
0   11  22  33
1   11  22  33
```

But in case of `pd.DataFrame(series)` since it is only a list, pandas will consider each element a new row.

which is equivalent to

```
pd.DataFrame([11,22,33])
```

and produces `3 rows` with `1 column` each

```
    0
0   11
1   22
2   33
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail.